# How to get chrome to autofill with asynchronous post

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, post

I have a form that because it is being submitted asynchronously

```
<input id="idField" type="text" placeholder="Enter id" />
<input type="button" value="submit ID"  id="submitBtn" />

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").on("click", "#submitBtn", function () {
        var id = $("idField").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "post.php",
            data: {
                "id": id
            },
            success: function () {
                alert("done");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Because of this, it seems ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/11746358/1252748 ) that google is refusing to autofill data I've entered in the past. What would be the best way around this?

Something like this?

```
<form method="post"> 
<input id="idField" type="text" placeholder="Enter id" />
<input type="button" id="submit" class="fr gen-btn" value="Submit" onClick="postForm()" /> 
</form>

function postForm() {
    var id = $("idField").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "post.php",
        data: {
            "id": id
        },
        success: function () {
            alert("done");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: what autofill you're talking about? Are you talking about the built-in or the jquery autosuggest?

Comment: @jQuerybeast built in browser-driven autofill

Answer (score 2):

Here's my suggested solution, after finding myself in a very similar situation.

1. Use a FORM tag to wrap your inputs
2. Make sure that the form is submitted to ensure that the browser stores the input field values for the next time (to display them with the "autofill" feature)

See HTML code below:

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="about:blank" target="_sink">
    <input id="idField" type="text" placeholder="Enter id" />
    <input id="submitBtn" type="button" value="submit ID" />
</form>
<iframe src="about:blank" name="_sink" style="display:none"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // assuming jQuery is available
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#myForm").submit(function () {
        var id = $("#idField").val();
        $.ajax({
          type: "post",
          url: "//localhost/dummy/post.php",
          data: {
            "id": id
          },
          success: function () {
            alert("done");
          },
          error: function () {
            alert("Error"); // we expect an error here since we're not actually posting to a real server
          }
        });
      });
    });
</script>
```

When you enter a value in the idField and press Enter (or click on the submit button), it tries to submit the form data to a remote server using an ajax post request.
In the meantime, it will also submit the form to the hidden iframe which makes Chrome able to store the values to re-use for the autofill.

I've also made a jsFiddle demo of this: http://jsfiddle.net/C5Qgf/