# Chrome autofill does not working on specific page

Tags: google-chrome

I have a set of pages in my site where I input similar data in each page.

I use very much the autofill of chrome to input the data without rewrite the entire sentence.

In a specific page, the autofill is not working. In another page of the same domain, the autofill works properly.

Anyone knows what the difference may have on this pages which causes this behavior?

Tks a lot

Comment: Could you provide an example of one of your forms that autofill and the one that doesn't?

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing your setup it's impossible to tell, but I stumbled upon two possible reasons.

1. There seems to be a bug/feature in Chrome 37 that prevents autofill on websites with **invalid ssl-certificates**.

   The issue is being discussed [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=408090).
2. There's also the possibility that you are using both post and get requests. autofill seems to only be available on post forms. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248488/what-would-cause-chrome-autofill-to-stop-working).