# Chrome AutoFill not working locally

Tags: google-chrome, autofill

I am building a site that supports autofill and I need to test some edge conditions locally.

Chrome happily offers to store the credentials on our deployed version but it will not ask locally.  I have tried to serve the site locally over HTTPS and served it under a different hostname than localhost with no luck.

Anyone know the details/restrictions on autocomplete in Chrome?

Thanks.

Comment: in 2020 I've got the same issue. Ever find out why?

Comment: Maybe related to https://stackoverflow.com/a/25741352/6009742